# Delete files in all folders named "deleted"

Tags: windows, batch-file, delete-file

Each user has a folder under their name named "deleted", I want to write a batch script to delete files in those folders for each user.

I also want it to only delete files older than a certain number of days, which I already have the script for:

```
forfiles -p "E:\%NameOfUser%\Deleted" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c del @PATH"
```

Obviously I need to put the folder paths into a variable or something like that but I'm not sure of the exact syntax.

Answer (score 0):

If the folder name is unique and will not be found anywhere else in the user's profile then this can work:

Test this and remove the LAST `echo` statement if it shows you the right files on the console.

```
forfiles -p "%userprofile%" -s -m *.* -d -10 -c "cmd /c if not @isdir=="TRUE" echo @PATH|find /i "\deleted\" >nul && echo del @PATH"
```